# How can I set an ASP.NET DropDownList.SelectedValue when its inside a FormView edit item template?

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

I'm trying to set the selected value of a DropDownList which sits inside the Edit template of a FormView. Whenever I access it, I get error:

> Object reference doesn't exist

I'm trying to set it in the following ways:

```
DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)FormView1.FindControl("ddlFrequency");
ddl.SelectedValue = "blah blah";
```

And also like:

```
((DropDownList)FormView1.FindControl("ddlFrequency")).SelectedValue = "blah blah";
```

How can I set this DropDownList.SelectedValue?

EDIT: Here is the entire method:

```
  protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String frequency = ((Label)(FormView1.FindControl("lblFrequency"))).Text;

    FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);

    String selectedValue = "0";

    switch (frequency.ToLower())
    {
        case "none": selectedValue = "0"; break;
        case "daily": selectedValue = "1"; break;
        case "weekly": selectedValue = "7"; break;
        case "monthly": selectedValue = "28"; break;
        case "bi-monthly": selectedValue = "56"; break;
        case "quarterly": selectedValue = "84"; break;
        case "semi-annually": selectedValue = "168"; break;
        case "annually": selectedValue = "365"; break;
        default: break;
    }

    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)FormView1.FindControl("ddlFrequency");
    ddl.SelectedValue = selectedValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind [FindControl() returns null on FormView until call DataBind()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171427/formview-findcontrol-returns-null-until-databind) .

Comment: @MAW74656: Glad my experience helped! :) I cut my teeth on that

Answer (score 1):

Well the edit template must be visible for FindControl to work.  You will probably have to use the `OnModeChanged` event to check for the Edit mode and then find the DropDownList.

Comment: Did you solve this problem of yours? I am having the same problem not sure which way to go