# .FindControl not working from my C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, findcontrol

I want to set some of my controls in a FormView manually and some from a SQL Data Source.

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
 <asp:FormView runat="server" DataSourceID="ds_Sco_Post_Reference_Data" ID="frmview1">
        <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="customer-details-inception-date">
                        <label class="applicationfont">Inception Date:</label>
                        <asp:TextBox CssClass="smallinputbox" runat="server" ID="txt_customer_details_inception_date" Text='<%# Bind("InceptionDate") %>' />
                </div>
                <div class="customer-details-renewal-date">
                        <label class="applicationfont">Renewal Date:</label>
                        <input class="smallinputbox" runat="server" id="txt_customer_details_renewal_date" readonly="readonly" />
                </div>
                <div class="customer-details-date-complient-logged">
                        <label class="applicationfont">Date Complient Logged:</label>
                        <asp:TextBox CssClass="smallinputbox" runat="server" id="txt_customer_details_date_complient_logged" />
                </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

I want to be able to find the control `txt_customer_details_date_complient_logged` and have tried alot of different C# code.

Here is an example that does not work:

```
FormView cph = (FormView)this.FindControl("frmview1");
TextBox t = ((TextBox)cph.FindControl("txt_customer_details_date_complient_logged"));
t.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("d");
```

Does anyone know why I cant get this to work?

Comment: asp.net has a tendency of prefixing the controls. To see if the control is still same name when the app is running, you must view source in the browser and search for the control name.

Comment: Have you tried: TextBox t = (TextBox)frmview1.FindControl("txt_customer_details_date_complient_logged");

Comment: @Bayeni 'ctl04$txt_customer_details_renewal_date' is the name that is appearing in source.

Comment: @KinyanjuiKamau Yes t is returning NuLL.

Comment: @user3129331 did you make sure that your databinding is working/your datasource is not null? If there are no results/if the control is not bound yet, this textbox won't be rendered. To test it you can do an emptyItemTemplate and bind the source - FormView.findControl should work fine.

Comment: @therak I am not databinding to this control i want to set it manually.

Comment: @user3129331 ok - but even though you don't wanna databind, a form list view won't render its ItemTemplate/EmptyItemTemplate if there are no items/ no databinding. you will never find the Control because it won't be rendered. you can still call FormView.DataBind even without a datasource. Just test it with EmptyItemTemplate, you will see.

Comment: Can you check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171427/formview-findcontrol-returns-null-until-databind